# Is there a standalone JavaScript compiler / interpreter with a console that I can use to practice JavaScript outside of the browser?

Tags: javascript

I would like to practice JavaScript and am looking for a stand-alone compiler or interpreter that I can run on my desktop as an EXE so I do not have to create HTML pages and run them in a browser just to test the JavaScript code. That would be a lot of boilerplate. I am looking for something that does for JavaScript what LINQPad does for LINQ.

I am pretty sure I saw something online but can't remember its name. You would type things and run them and test them out online.

I am aware that most browsers today provide some kind of a JavaScript editor or sandbox or console where you can do the same thing. I was just curious if I could do something similar as a stand-alone process.

And if there isn't, even if I can be reminded of that online thing where you tried your code snippets, that would be great. I think it was called gist or something else that usually I used to know like the back of my hand but it desperately escapes me now.

Comment: use any editor. may be brackets?

Comment: There are a couple of online tools for that, the most popular are http://plnkr.co and http://codepen.io

Comment: @thllbrg: Awesome. Thank you so much for telling me about these tools. I had no idea. I mostly did server side C# and the usual little bit of Javascript that goes with CRUD Web development. I am now beginning to explore JavaScript seriously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a lot of:

- Node.js
- JSDB
- JavaLikeScript
- ShellJS
- etc.

Mozilla has a large list with standalone Javascript shells: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Shells

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. There's a tool written in node.js which takes out the chrome dev tool gives it as a node.js utility that can be run locally.

> Learn more about it
>
> https://github.com/auchenberg/chrome-devtools-app

**Update**

2. Secondly why dont you use Scratchpad that is built in Firefox that you can use to write js code and run it instantaneously.I use it sometimes as well.

> Learn about it :
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Scratchpad

3. Your browser has it all embedded into it as well.So doing some js inside your browser console is a good option to start with as well.Some drawbacks however includes debugging i guess.But for start i guess it should be good.
   I have added the 3rd point seeing that you want something lightweight.

Comment: Sweet. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use NetBeans to do this.

Comment: Yes, I could. And I could even have used Visual Studio. But they're too heavy for just this sort of a thing. I was inclined to using something lightweight and standalone.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a console and a compiler, how about trying Node JS? It's designed for Server side programming, but it's still JavaScript;

Comment: Yes, node is something I definitely have wanted to use and this might be a good opportunity. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the online thing I was trying to remember the name of. It's Fiddle. JS Fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/

And there's a fiddle for many languages.

Now if someone told me of a stand-alone desktop executable environment that had a JavaScript engine embedded into it, that would be great.

I know that the Windows scripting environment will let me run JS on the command line but still, I am looking for a stand-alone executable that I can launch anytime and it lets me type JavaScript code into it and execute it. Is there such a thing?

Comment: A small suggestion , you should not be asking question in an answer

Comment: @cafebabe1991 Thank you. Sorry about that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is just a browser. 
You just have to create a html page with any text editor and open that file in a browser. No need to set up a web server for this task.

Many text editor like Dreamweaver, brackets and other Komodo have a built in function to do the "preview in browser "

JavaScript is a client side language so the interpreter is in the browser not in the web server

Comment: Kindly read my question.

Comment: I have and I keep repeating that I don't understand why you should reinvent the wheel. Btw jsfiddle is a sharing tool for your js code. Node.js is a web server based on JavaScript. So you can do nothing else than using your already installed and working browser:) what is wrong with that???

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the browser. I was curious.

Comment: Ah, ok. Please note that any browser has a different JavaScript rendering engine (Node is based on chrome's one) and they are periodically updated. So you can have some minor issues running a standalone engine.

Comment: Yes, I know that. :-)